# Currency symbol is missing when switching

Tags: currency, magento2.2.0

I am using Magento version 2.2.0
URL: http://www.hit-counts.com/vinca/
The currency symbol ($),(SAR) is missing when switch the English store to Arabic store. I removed the code as well from this root path but nothing changed.

> /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/ar_SA.xml

```
<numbers>
    <currencyFormats numberSystem="latn">
        <currencyFormatLength>
            <currencyFormat type="standard">
                <pattern>¤#0.00</pattern>
            </currencyFormat>
        </currencyFormatLength>
    </currencyFormats>
</numbers>
```

Comment: i have display sar curreny symbol in your site. please check using clear browser cache.

Comment: It is displaying in English Store but when you switch to arabic store the symbol will not display. Well i have flushed cache magento as well

Comment: Hello rakesh i have reload my page again and it works thank you for help .

Comment: Hi @Faizan : I also get this issue, please let me know how you fix this? thanks